# What's the HBase read performance when data resides on HDFS(HFile)

Tags: hbase

As we know, data in memory store will be flushed to HDFS as HFile when data in memory store reaches a threshold

When I want to get a piece of data via row key, but the data is on HDFS, how does HBase guarantee the retrieval speed(or random access speed)? Looks it will be much slower than retrieval from memory store?

Comment: If the underlying storage is SSD rather than SDD the performance is still quite good once data is flushed. In fact in our use-cases, we flush and major-compact periodically on purpose, because we have too many deletes in our job and that clogs up the scans. If your underlying is HDD then performance suffers greatly. Also tinker around with properties like dfs.client.read.shortcircuit, which enables an RS to read the data locally directly if it happens to be locates on the RS.

Comment: @VS_FF, Thanks, that's great answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From HBase [Reference Guide](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#block.cache):

> HBase provides two different BlockCache implementations to cache data
>   read from HDFS: the default on-heap `LruBlockCache` and the `BucketCache`,
>   which is (usually) off-heap...
>
> `LruBlockCache` is the original
>   implementation, and is entirely within the Java heap. BucketCache is
>   optional and mainly intended for keeping block cache data off-heap...

HBase also collects block cache stats, and presents them through its web UI. With proper tuning you can achieve hit ratios of 90%-95%, so you're still reading from memory most of the time.